# Symfony2 new bundle routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have create new bundle in src\Moda\CategoryBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

and a change routing to:

```
namespace Moda\CategoryBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/show", name="_show")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die('test');
        return array();
    }
}
```

and my routing.yml in app/config

```
moda_category:
    resource: "@ModaCategoryBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

This links dosnt work:

localhost/web/app_dev.php/category/show

localhost/web/app_dev.php/show

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: After you change your config did you clear the cache ??

Comment: I suggest set name for the route and check if it is visible by the router. You can check in that way: app/console router:debug route_name

Comment: I set name and check routing by  app/console router:debug I see that it is visible _show ANY    ANY    ANY  /show I have alsow clear cache but it still doesnt work. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should import the `config.yml` file inside your bundle.
So instead of :

```
moda_category:
    resource: "@ModaCategoryBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Change it to:

```
moda_category:
    resource: "@ModaCategoryBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

And then add the routes you need inside that file.

Comment: Why do you whant to write the route in the  @ModaCategoryBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml file. All the point of using annotation is to config the route inside your controller file.